# iOS - Custom Button With A Depressed State

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton, uiimage

I realize that there has to be a a ton of guides to do this but I can't find it...

What I am trying to do is use a button with a custom image in it and when you press the button have the image change to another "pressed" version of the button.

Comment: +1 for the "depressed state" :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I believe you need is:

```
[button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Comment: Wouldn't you also need to set the button to selected state at some point (maybe after touch up inside)?  Unless the OP wanted the image change while the button is being touched, then use UIControlStateHighlighted instead.

Comment: You would need to set other images for other states if you wanted images for other states yes

Answer (score 5):

If you don't like James Webster's solution, you can also do the same through interface builder. Select your button and from the properties find the "state config" list and pick "Selected". Then if you set image, title etc, you will get different graphics and text if you do `[button setSelected:YES];`

Comment: But in either case, you likely want the "highlighted" state, not the "selected" state.